# Auth token resets after redirect in Silex

Tags: php, security, oauth, silex

Using opauth to signup through facebook and twitter, using [this](https://github.com/icehero/silex-opauth/blob/master/example/example.php) example

```
$app->on(OpauthExtension::EVENT_SUCCESS, function ($e) use ($app) {
    $userProvider = new UserProvider($app);
    $userProvider->oauthLogin($e->getSubject()); //stores user and creates session
    //echo $app['security']->getToken(); THERE IS works 

    $e->setArgument('result', $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('_homepage')));
});
```

if I call `$app['security']->getToken();` it works on event dispatcher, but after redirect it falls down to anon. user.
Login through form forks fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in UserProviderInterface. refreshUser method serched user by wrong field.